# Smarty function return a smarty tag which is not interpreted

Tags: php, smarty

I have create a custom function smarty for my CMS :

```
{$page->title|inter}
```

So, this tag, when it's interpreted, call my custom function `smarty_modifier_inter`, retrieve a html code, do some actions and then return it.

In this html, I can have other smarty tag. But, I just see, if a function smarty return smarty code, this smarty code is not interpreted...

So, I have on my page a tag like `{$page->title|inter}` not interpreted.

Do you have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify the question or add a simple example of what it shows and what's supposed to show?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you mean that smarty_modifier_inter() returns smarty code and you expect this smarty code to be parsed by itself? Smarty will only parse your template once for each modifier, so it won't parse the returned smarty tags (actually I assume it will run all functions at the original template body, so it will not parse any returned smarty tag).

One way to achieve what you're looking for, is to implement recursion inside your modifier. Say, for example, that your modifier looks like this:

```
function smarty_modifier_inter($string)
{
    $html = some_function($string);  //This may contain a smarty tag, such as {$page->title|inter}
    return $html;
}
```

You could change it to something like:

```
function smarty_modifier_inter($string)
{
    $html = some_function($string);  //This may contain a smarty tag, such as {$page->title|inter}
    if (preg_match("/".preg_quote("{$")."/", $html)) {     //A very quick and dirty way to see if there are any smarty variables within your template
        $html = smarty_modifier_inter($html);  //This may contain a smarty tag, such as {$page->title|inter}
    } 

    return $html;
}
```

This will repeatedly run smarty_modifier_inter to your string, until it contains no more smarty variables. Obviously this is very susceptible to endless loops, so use with caution!

If you are sure that there's going to be a single level of recursion, then you can simply run at most one more time your function on your data

Answer (score 0):

Smarty functions are a means of going from the input (a Smarty template) to the output (usually HTML); they are not a way of generating further Smarty code which will be rendered recursively.

You may be able to do what you want with a [pre-filter](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.prefilters.postfilters.tpl), which runs over the Smarty template source *before* it is processed by Smarty itself, but this is not as easy as writing a custom function.

More promisingly, Smarty3 includes a [`string:` resource](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/resources.string.tpl), which allows you to render a string as though it were the contents of a template.

So in your custom function, you could have something like this:

```
function smarty_function_get_more_smarty($params, $smarty_instance)
{
    $code = get_code_from_somewhere($params['foo'], $params['bar']);
    // $code might be something like '<h1>My Awesome Site - {$title}</h1>'
    return $smarty_instance->fetch('string:' . $code);
}
```

Note that I haven't tested this code or ever used this feature, so please read the manual for escaping options, and the distinction between `string:` and `eval:`.

Also, although this isn't explicitly recursive on the face of it, if `$code` ends up with another call to the same custom function, you will end up back in the same function, so make sure you protect against infinite recursion somehow!